# Passing multiple variables to blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

How to pass multiple variables to blade view in Laravel ?

Say I have to pass `$var1` and `$var2` to view 'welcome'.

Comment: You ask question and answer it for 23 secs ? lol

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer clearly, 'Posting as for others it might be useful'. 
I found the information and posted this question and answer on this forum for others as it might be useful to someone who is looking for it.

Comment: @Goper Leo Zosa, a lot of guys do that here. My opinion is this should be prohibited, it really looks like cheating to gain reputation.

Comment: @Alexey First apologies to interfere but this shouldn't be prohibited as it might be useful for others..but yes because of cheating scope they shouldn't award any answer points or up-vote points for these type of question-answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Posting as for others it might be useful, one can use two approaches,

`with` function, 
Pass them in the form of array to the view with the help of `with` function

```
$data = array('var1'=>$var1, 'var2'=>$var2);
            return view('welcome')->with($data);
```

`compact` function, Use `compact` function to pass the data

```
$var1= "variable 1";
$var2 = "variable 2";
return view('welcome', compact('var1', 'var2'));
```

And in both cases, call the variables simply by name in the view

`{{ $var1 }} and {{ $var2 }}`

P.S. In second approach variables are being simply passed inside compact with just names and without any $ sign.